# How to load multiple web pages each in an individual div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, load

Have not been able to find an answer by searching yet. So I figured I would post my question. Trying to load multiple pages into multiple divs. Works ok if there is only one on a page, but not more than one.

Example: trying to load page1.html to `div#frameOne` and page2.html to `div#frameTwo` when the page loads (not using a button or link).

HTML:

```
<div id="frameOne"></div>
<div id="frameTwo"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#frameOne').load('page1.html');
    $('#frameTwo').load('page2.html');
});
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Does JS console say anything? Seems you're doing everything right (simlar code works for me)...

Comment: hmmmmm.....I am pulling in a jsonp feed in both of the pages using the google api that I am trying to pull into the divs.....maybe that's the problem....will have to experiment a bit...I did not try just html pages

Comment: James...thank you for making me think about this a bit more....evidently the problem was that I had two sep web pages but was using the same id's etc pulling in and formatting the feeds they populated....so when they were combined into sep divs on one page, it caused conflicts.....changed the ids of one of the pages...and now it works.....thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to insert iframe in your div

```
<iframe src="URL"frameborder="0" style="width: 894px; height: 555px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will load the pages into the selected divs after the page is loaded:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#frameOne').load('page1.html');
        $('#frameTwo').load('page2.html');
    });
});
```